# Validadores de actualización y "this" en mongoose

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, express, mongoose

muchas gracias por tomarse el tiempo.

Tengo dos campos en un Schema de Mongoose: ***campoUno*** y ***campoDos***.

```
const tareaSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    campoUno: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    campoDos: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        validate: {
            validator: function (value) {
                return this.campoUno=== value;
            },
            message: 'Los campos son diferentes...'
        }
    }
});

const Tarea= mongoose.model('Tarea', tareaSchema);
```

Estoy utilizando un validador personalizado para comparar los campos uno y dos, pero para ello necesito recurrir a la palabra  ***"this"***, el problema es que el validador sólo funciona al crear un nuevo documento tal como dice la documentación de mongoose: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#update-validators-and-this.

Esto no funciona cuando actualizamos un documento utilizando `findOneAndUpdate()` y todo lo referente a  `find()`.

Una solución sería, buscar el documento y actualizarlo manualmente:

```
app.put('/tarea/:id', (req, res)=>{
    const tarea = Tarea.findById(req.params.id, (err, tareaEncontrado)=>{
        tareaEncontrado.campoUno= req.body.campoUno;
        tareaEncontrado.campoDos= req.body.campoDos;
        tareaEncontrado.save();
    })
})
```

Ahora bien, si todos mis Esquemas tienen validadores de este tipo que utilizan ***"this"***:

***¿Esto significa que nunca podré utilizar los métodos de actualización como `findOneAndUpdate()`?***.

***¿Existe alguna otra forma de validar campos en función de otros campos, sin ultizar "this"?***

Gracias de antemano a todos.

Answer (score 0):

Sí, existe otra forma de validar tus campos, esto es creando validaciones como parte de un proceso *pre* actualización.

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea realizar la validación de campos durante un proceso de actualización de documento. Sin embargo, la función de validación no se ejecuta aunque la misma está definida en el [esquema](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html) de datos de [Mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/).

**SOLUCIÓN**

Podrías usar una función [*middleware*](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html) [*Pre*](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#pre) de [tipo *Query*](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#types-of-middleware) para los métodos [`findOneAndUpdate`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOneAndUpdate) (incluye [`findByIdAndUpdate`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate)), [`updateOne`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-updateOne) y [`update`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-update).

Como en las funciones *middleware* de tipo *Query* el objeto `this` se refiere al [objeto *Query*](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#Query) y no al documento, debemos utilizar el objeto `update` de dicho *Query*. Entonces si queremos acceder al documento de actualización del Objeto *Query* usaremos el método [`getUpdate()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html#query_Query-getUpdate), y comparamos los campos usando dicho documento de actualización.

Por ejemplo, podemos escribir nuestra función de validación como:

```js
const updateValidation = function(next) {
  let update = this.getUpdate();
  if(Object.entries(update).length) {
    if(update.$set) {
      if(update.$set.campoUno === update.$set.campoDos) return next();
    } else {
      if(update.campoUno === update.campoDos) return next();
    }
    return next(new Error('Los campos son diferentes....'));
  }
  return next();
}
```

En la función anterior estamos evaluando los campos llamados `campoUno` y `campoDos`. Si ambos son iguales seguimos con el proceso de actualización, de lo contrario devolvemos un error como argumento de la función `next()` que detendrá el proceso de actualización devolviendo el error como resultado de la misma.

Nótese que tenemos 2 casos: en el primero se usa un objeto con el operador [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/index.html) y en el segundo sin dicho operador. Y es que cuando realizamos una actualización, podemos (debemos) usar el operador `$set` para indicarle a MongoDB que no reemplace el documento almacenado por el documento que estamos enviando sino que actualice únicamente los campos que se envían en dicho objeto.

Luego podemos usar nuestra función de actualización como un *middleware* para operaciones *pre* (previas).

En este caso lo haremos para las siguiente operaciones:

```js
// El esquema
const DatoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  // ...
}, {timestamps: {updatedAt: 'updated', createdAt: 'created'}, collection: 'datos'});

// La función de validación:
const updateValidation = function(next) {
  let update = this.getUpdate();
  if(Object.entries(update).length) {
    if(update.$set) {
      if(update.$set.campoUno === update.$set.campoDos) return next();
    } else {
      if(update.campoUno === update.campoDos) return next();
    }
    return next(new Error('Los campos son diferentes....'));
  }
  return next();
}

// la declaración de middleware:
DatoSchema.pre('update', updateValidation);
DatoSchema.pre('updateOne', updateValidation);
DatoSchema.pre('findOneAndUpdate', updateValidation); // incluye findByIdAndUpdate

// el modelo
const Dato = mongoose.model('Dato', DatoSchema);
```

Cada vez que actualicemos datos usando alguno de los métodos descritos, se ejecutará nuestra función de validación.

```js
Dato.findByIdAndUpdate(id, {$set: req.body}, {new: true} callback); // <- usando $set
Dato.findOneAndUpdate(filtro, req.body, {new: true}, callback); // sin usar $set
Dato.update(filtro, {$set: req.body}, callback); // <- usando $set
Dato.updateOne(filtro, req.body, callback); // sin usar $set
```

De esta forma puedes validar los campos al realizar una actualización sobre un documento, sin necesidad de hacer un `find()` y luego un `save()`.

Comment: muy excelente tu explicación, me podrías aclarar un poco más sobre el uso del objeto `$set`?