# Acutalizar subdocumento en mongodb

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

Tengo los siguientes esquemas:

```
const AutorSchema = new Schema({

    nombre: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "El nombre es requerido"]
    },
    apellido:{
        type: String,
        required: [true, "El apellido es requerido"]
    }

})

const LibroSchema = new Schema({

    titulo: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "El titulo es requerido"]
    },

    editorial:{
        type: String,
        required: [true, "La editorial es requerida"]
    },

    autor:{
        type: AutorSchema,
        required: ["El autor es requerido"]
    }


})
```

Cuando quiero actualizar la información del autor y solo quiero modificar uno de los atributos de Autor, se guarda unicamente el campo que quería actualizar y los demás desaparecen. Por ejemplo:

```
const autor = {
    data:{
        apellido: "Perez"
    }
}

Libro.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.params.id}, autor);

/* 

Devuelve => 
    {
        titulo: "Libro1",
        editorial: "Editorial1",
        autor:{
            apellido: "Perez"
        }
    }

*/
```

Como se puede ver el atributo "nombre" del autor desaparece y queda solo el nuevo apellido. Como puedo modificar algunos de los atributos y mantener los demás?

Comment: mira [este ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/388456/28035) la idea es usar $set : {...}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tal como comenta @JackNavaRow, debes usar el operador [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/index.html) para indicarle a MongoDB que se va a reemplazar un campo y no todo el documento.

Además, el campo que vas a actualizar, al tratarse de un campo en un documento embebido, debes indicarlo usando la notación de punto.

Por ejemplo:

```js
let update = {
  $set: {
    'autor.nombre': 'Nicolas' // <- notación de punto sobre autor.nombre
  }
}

Libro.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.params.id}, update, {new: true})
.then( ... )
.catch( ... );
```

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

**EDICIÓN**

En tu [comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/389220/acutalizar-subdocumento-en-mongodb/389231#comment697250_389231) haces una pregunta bastante interesante.

Si alguno de los campos del `json` recibido es `undefined`, entonces no deberíamos hacer la actualización, ya que la misma establece el campo a `null` en el documento.

La solución es construir el objeto de actualización basados en la información recibida.

Por ejemplo:

```js
let update = {};
let $set = {};
Object.keys(json_recibido).forEach(key => {
  if(json_recibido[key]) { // si el valor es distinto de undefined o null
    $set[key] = json_recibido[key];
  }
});

if(Object.keys($set).length) {
  update.$set = $set;
}
// ahora update sólo contiene los campos que no sean undefined o null
```

Veamos un ejemplo del código anterior funcionando:

```js
const jsons = [
  {nombre: 'Mauricio', apellido: 'Contreras'},
  {nombre: 'Gonzalo JSBianchi', apellido: undefined},
  {nombre: 'Nicolas', apellido: undefined},
  {nombre: null, apellido: 'Cavilla'},
  {nombre: null, apellido: undefined}
  
];

jsons.forEach(json_recibido => {
  let update = {};
  let $set = {};
  Object.keys(json_recibido).forEach(key => {
    if(json_recibido[key]) { // si el valor es distinto de undefined o null
      $set[key] = json_recibido[key];
    }
  });

  if(Object.keys($set).length) {
    update.$set = $set;
  }
  console.log(update);
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Si se quiere actualizar el autor anterior y se recibe  un json, por ejemplo {nombre: "Nicolas"}, haría lo siguiente  $set: { 'autor.nombre': json.nombre, 'autor.apellido': json.apellido}, esto esta bien?

Comment: @NicolasCavilla, eso es correcto. El operador `$set` actualizará cada campo que indiques, sin alterar el resto de campos del documento anidado. Ahora, si vas a reemplazar un autor por otro, tal vez deberías considerar reemplazar todo el documento, ya que se trata de otro autor por lo tanto otro documento. Al reemplazarlo se cambia todo, incluso el campo `_id`, lo cual es consistente si estás cambiando el autor. Saludos

Comment: en el caso anterior, si el valor de `json.apellido` es `undefined` ¿en la base de datos no se guardaria `autor.apellido: null`? ¿Como se podría evitar esto?

Comment: @NicolasCavilla, acabo de editar la respuesta para aclarar tu última duda. Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias @MauricioContreras, excelente respuesta, para que funcione en mi código tuve que hacer un pequeño cambio en la asignación:
`$set['autor.'+key] = json_recibido[key];`