# Mongoose problema al actualizar campos requeridos en documentos embebidos de Mongoose

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, express, mongoose

Tengo un ***Schema*** de ***mongoose*** con un ***documento embebido***:

```
var childSchema = new Schema({
   nombre: {
      type: 'string',
      required: [true, 'El nombre es requerido...']
   },
   direccion: {
      type: 'string'
   }
});

var parentSchema = new Schema({
  // campos propios del Parent
  child: childSchema
});
```

El problema es que cuando trato de actualizar desde *parentSchema*, el campo ***direccion*** que se encuentra en el documento hijo o subdocumento *childSchema* y que no es requerido, me sale error de tipo: ***ValidatorError***: ***"El nombre es requerido..."***.

Esto significa que para actualizar con `findByIdAndUpdate()` debo enviar de manera obligatoria todos los campos del subdocumento *childSchema*, lo cual contradice al postulado de mongoose: ***"Los validadores de actualización solo se ejecutan en rutas actualizadas"***, https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#update-validators-only-run-on-updated-paths.

```
// DATOS ENVIADOS DESDE POSTMAN
{
    // campos propios del Parent
    "child": {
        "direccion": "Nueva dirección"
    }
}
```

***¿Cuál es la forma de solucionar esto?***

Gracias

Comment: Ya te di una [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/387851/validadores-de-actualización-y-this-en-mongoose/388456#388456) al respecto. La validación la haces con una función [middleware](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html). Si vas a actualizar sólo un campo de un documento, entonces debes usar `$set`, además el nombre del campo debe ser especificado con notación de punto: `Model.findByIdAndUpdate(id, {$set: { 'child.direccion': 'valor'} }, { new: true }, callback);`. Saludos

Answer (score 2):

Ocupas hacer lo siguiente:

```
ParentSchema.findById(miId).exec().then(parent=>{
   if(!parent) throw "No existe el id"

   //Si existe entonces actualizas la propiedad.

   parent.child.nombre = "Nuevo nombre"
   //Mongo detecta los cambios echos automaticamente y se aplican las validaciones
   // solo al campo que se modifico
   return parent.save()
})
.then(parentGuardado=>{
  return res.send(guardado)
})
.catch(e=> next(e))
```

De esta manera cumples la condición mencionada sobre la validacion de datos. Esta forma es la recomendada por la documentacion de mongoose.

---

Otra forma de abordar este problema es utilizando  `updateOne` con la opcion `runValidator:true`

```
ParentSchema.updateOne(
    {_id:idParent}, 
    {$set:{"child.nombre":"Nuevo nombre}, 
    {rundValidators: true}}}
)
.exec()
.then(...)
.catch(...)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @Legna, le estoy muy agradecido.

Answer (score 2):

Lo que te hace falta usar es el operador [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/index.html) para realizar el proceso de actualización de forma atómica.

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea actualizar un documento de MongoDB, el cual tiene la restricción `required` en algunos de los campos de un documento embebido. La restricción es parte de un esquema que se usa como tipo de dato embebido en otro documento.

Sin embargo al enviar el documento a actualizar, usando [`findByIdAndUpdate`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate) o [`findOneAndUpdate`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate), se devuelve el error de restricción sobre los campos que no se van a actualizar, ya que los mismos no están siendo declarados en el documento de actualización.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Si bien ya tienes una solución en la otra respuesta aportada, una de las desventajas de hacerlo de esa forma es que pierdes la [*atomicidad*](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/write-operations-atomicity/index.html) de la operación.

Lo que debes hacer es usar el operador `$set` para indicarle a MongoDB que se realizará una actualización exclusiva sobre los campos especificados dentro de dicho objeto, de esta forma el resto de campos que existan en el modelo de datos no se verán afectados.

Al tratarse de un documento embebido, los campos de dicho documento debemos indicarlos usando la [notación de punto](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation). Para esta caso, si deseamos actualizar el campo llamado `field_1` del documento almacenado en `child`, debemos escribirlo como:

```
"child.field_1": <value>
```

Por ejemplo, teniendo el siguiente modelo de datos:

```js
const ChildSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  field_1: {
    type: String,
    required: 'El campo es necesario'
  },
  field_2: {
    type: Number,
    required: 'El campo es necesario'
  }
});

const ParentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  top_field_1: {
    type: String,
    required: 'El campo es necesario'
  },
  top_field_2: {
    type: Number,
    required: 'El campo es necesario'
  },
  child: {
    type: ChildSchema
  }
});
```

Entonces, si desde [Postman](https://www.postman.com/) (como plantea el OP) se envía el siguiente objeto:

```js
{
  top_field_1: 'Valor',
  child: {
    field_2: 8367
  }
}
```

En nuestro *backend* al recibir dicho documento, debemos hacer una serie de operaciones para especificar los campos sobre los que haremos la actualización.

Por ejemplo:

```js
// req.body contiene el objeto en cuestión:
/*
{
  top_field_1: 'Valor',
  child: {
    field_2: 8367
  }
}
*/
// incializamos nuestros objetos de actualización
let update = {}
let $set = {}

// escribimos el objeto $set según corresponda
if(Object.keys(req.body).length) {
  Object.keys(req.body).forEach(key => {
    if(key !== 'child') {
      $set[key] = req.body[key];
    } else {
      if(Object.keys(req.body.child).length) {
        Object.keys(req.body.child).forEach(embbededKey => {
          $set[`child.${embbededKey}`] = req.body.child[embbededKey]; // <- notación de punto
        });
      }
    }
  });
}

// actualizamos el objeto update según sea necesario
if(Object.keys($set).length) {
  update.$set = $set;
}

// usamos el objeto update para realizar la actualización.
Parent.findByIdAndUpdate(id, update, {runValidators: true, new: true}, callback); // <- opción de ejecutar la validaciones establecida a 'true'
```

De esta forma sólo se actualizan los valores pasados dentro del objeto `$set` en el documento de actualización `update` que pasamos como argumento.

Para ver cómo queda nuestro objeto `update`:

```js
let req = {
  body: {
    top_field_1: 'Valor',
    child: {
      field_2: 8367
    }
  }
}

let update = {}
let $set = {}

// escribimos el objeto $set según corresponda
if(Object.keys(req.body).length) {
  Object.keys(req.body).forEach(key => {
    if(key !== 'child') {
      $set[key] = req.body[key];
    } else {
      if(Object.keys(req.body.child).length) {
        Object.keys(req.body.child).forEach(embbededKey => {
          $set[`child.${embbededKey}`] = req.body.child[embbededKey];
        });
      }
    }
  });
}

// actualizamos el objeto update según sea necesario
if(Object.keys($set).length) {
  update.$set = $set;
}

// mostramos
console.log(update);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

De esta forma podemos actualizar el documento sin necesidad de escribir todos los campos requeridos, ya que la validación sólo se realizará sobre los campos establecidos en el objeto `$set`.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Mauricio, le quedo muy agradecido.

Comment: Es necesario hacer en el backend una serie de operaciones para especificar los campos sobre los que haremos la actualización? no hay otra forma de enviar los datos desde postman? puesto que estos campos posteriormente van a ser enviados desde un formulario del frontend. Gracias de nuevo @Mauricio

Comment: Podrías enviar los datos directamente dentro de un objeto `$set`, además puedes usar una solicitud tipo `PUT` para diferenciar la ruta de una solicitud tipo `POST`. Saludos

Comment: Aunque pensándolo bien, eso crearía una dependencia muy fuerte entre tu *front* y tu *back*. Así que sí, lo ideal es hacerlo en el *back* todo. Que el *front* sólo se encargue de enviar una solicitud `PUT` con los campos a modificar. En el *back* estableces la lógica adecuada para que todo funcione. Si cambias luego de sistema en el *back*, no tienes necesidad de tocar el *front*.

Comment: Muy agradecido @Mauricio.